# Adding 'vote' buttons to django objects

Tags: python, django, forms

At the moment I have multiple 'Photo' objects being displayed on a pages template.

The `Photo` Model has a field 'score' which has a default value of 0.

I am struggling to find a way to add two buttons ("up"/"down") in the template related to each object so when the "up" button is clicked it adds 1 to that particular Photo objects score, or if "down" is clicked it subtracts 1 from the score and once the button has been clicked it updates the photos score value in the database.

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

I have looked into using ModelForms and been through the django tutorial on forms but I am struggling to work out how to do it.

Comment: Is the problem that you want the up/down to work without redirecting on another view? If so, you need to use javascript to make ajax calls. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be very straightforward. The up/down vote button could be just a link that links to your view method with photo id in url. In your view method you take the photo id and search for corresponding photo, then update the score.

I provide a simple example here, you need to read [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) on how each detail works to complete it:

template.html:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <a href="upvote/{{ photo.id }}">up</a>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^upvote/(?P<photo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.upvote, name='upvote'),
```

views.py

```
def upvote(request, photo_id):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=photo_id)
    photo.score += 1
    photo.save()
    return HttpResponse('your-photo-list-view')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I didn't realise it could be that straight forward for some reason, I think I was overthinking it!